# jQuery ProgressBar - Object doesnt support?

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

Just trying to add a jQuery progressbar on the site.
I did what the jquery docs said adding a div with id = progressbar

`<div id="progressbar"></div>`

Then I have:

```
<script src="include/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: 37 }); //dies here
   });
```

But I see object does not support this property or method in IE.  It points to line "21" char 3 which is just that line:

```
  $('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: 37 }); //dies here
```

Do I need to do something else to get this progress bar to display ?

### Edit

I also added:

`<script src="include/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
So now I dont see the error but I also don't see a progress bar...

Comment: I think you need JQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Comment: @sje397 - Ok now I added `<script src="include/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and placed the file in my project, no error now..but also no progress bar...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ahh I forgot to add the css file, its working now.

Comment: You should accept the first valid answer, not your own comment (especially if it is the same solution)

Answer (score 4):

Include the jQuery, jQuery UI js file, and jQuery UI CSS file and it should show up.  My guess is that you are missing the CSS file.